# Wordpress not available to file using wp-env for xdebug requests

Tags: debug

I'm using [Wp-env](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-env) to develop a plugin as it's a pretty robust wrapper for Docker that includes phpunit and xdebug.

However, I have been struggling to get xDebug working.

- From my_plugin directory run `wp-env start`... await build
- set .vscode/launch.json as per docs:

```json
{
  "name": "Listen for XDebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "port": 9003,
  "pathMappings": {
    "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin": "${workspaceFolder}/"
  }
}
```

- run `wp-env start --xdebug`
- open main plugin file and add breakpoint in VS Code and try to Run and Debug
- Result: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function plugin_dir_path"
  (and if I add `!defined( 'ABSPATH' ) die()`, it is tripped.)

I'm new to this tool so expecting it's a newbie error. Seems like xDebug should be starting at the Wordpress entrypoint, but isn't.

There is one more item of note, though. In `wp-env logs`:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(, referer: http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the issue ended up being is embarrassing!

I had used the xdebug configuration as the *entire* `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Listen for XDebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "port": 9003,
  "pathMappings": {
    "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin": "${workspaceFolder}/"
  }
}
```

As opposed to the *correct*:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin": "${workspaceFolder}/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Older and wiser!

For other debuggers, this was my path:

The output of adding to index file: `xdebug_info();` includes:

> [Step Debug] Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).

and

> [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Within the docker container:

`/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`

contains expected: `zend_extension=xdebug`

In the host, OS X computer:

```
$ nslookup host.docker.internal
Server:     2001:578:3f::10
Address:    2001:578:3f::10#53

** server can't find host.docker.internal: NXDOMAIN
```

And in the container, `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.25.0.5  9cf0413e6c4f
```

Also `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

On the guest, installed `apt-get update && apt install dnsutils`, for

```
# nslookup host.docker.internal
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   host.docker.internal
Address: 192.168.65.2
```

Adding this to my (host computer) hosts file: `127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal` did not help.

#### Wait a minute?

Why does VS Code keep telling me there isn't a `launch.json` file, then opening it when I direct it to create one? And... see above. : )